# why does my ide shows error saying unsupported operand types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

```
def intToBin(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n > 1:
        return ((n % 2 + 10 * intToBin((n/2))))

a = 6
b = intToBin(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass int(n/2) into function because if n/2 is floating it will cause an error in code when the value is less than 1.
see below solution

```
def intToBin(n): 
    if n == 0: 
        return 0 
    elif n == 1: 
        return 1 
    elif n > 1: 
        return ((n % 2 + 10 * intToBin(int(n/2))))

a = 6
b = intToBin(a) 
print(b)
```

OUTPUT :

```
110
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
def intToBin(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n > 1:
        return ((n % 2 + 10 * intToBin((n/2))))

a = 6
b = intToBin(a)
print(b)
```

In python3, `n/2` is a float division operation. So in recursive call, a float is being passed. Now when this float is less than 1, there is no `if-else` block that satisfies the condition, hence the function returns None. The multiplication of 10 with None from the recursive call results in error.

For debugging and better understanding, print n:

```
def intToBin(n):
    print(n)
    ...rest of your code
```

which outputs:

```
6
3.0
1.5
0.75
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zz.py", line 11, in <module>
    b = intToBin(a)
  File "zz.py", line 8, in intToBin
    return ((n % 2 + 10 * intToBin((n/2))))
  File "zz.py", line 8, in intToBin
    return ((n % 2 + 10 * intToBin((n/2))))
  File "zz.py", line 8, in intToBin
    return ((n % 2 + 10 * intToBin((n/2))))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

To fix:
As answered above, either use `int(n/2)` or `n//2` or have a default base or return case of the function.